# Expressjs password field validation

Tags: node.js, validation, express

I am building a simple user registration page(using node and express) with username and password and confirm password field.

Is there any builtin way for expressjs or is there any other npm package availble to check if the text entered in password and confirm password field is same or not ?

Comment: You can simply use type safe comparisons `if (password === confirmationPassword)`. This will return `true` if both the password and the confirmation password are entirely equal in value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator)

For example:

```
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('confirmPassword', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
```